Image.gt: If one image has no bands, the other must also have no bands. Got 0 and 1 using Landsat 8
I am getting error Image.gt: If one image has no bands, the other must also have no bands. Got 0 and 1.:
var imageCollection = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T2_L2"),
    geometry = 
    /* color: #0b4a8b */
    /* displayProperties: [
      {
        "type": "rectangle"
      }
    ] */
    ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[44.5346944926502, 38.37189110732085],
          [44.5346944926502, 36.97192200651999],
          [46.2925069926502, 36.97192200651999],
          [46.2925069926502, 38.37189110732085]]], null, false);

var coordinates = [
  [42.000552219688586, 38.18969302118053],
  [43.868228000938586, 38.18969302118053],
  [43.868228000938586, 39.209978258633186],
  [42.000552219688586, 39.209978258633186],
  [42.000552219688586, 38.18969302118053]
];

var roi = ee.Geometry.Polygon(coordinates);

Map.addLayer(roi)

var time_start = '2013', time_end = '2021'

var landsat = imageCollection
.filterDate(time_start, time_end)
.filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 10))
.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(6,9,'month'))
.filterBounds(geometry).map(function(img){
  var bands = img.select('SR_.*').multiply(2.75e-05).add(-0.2);
  var ndwi = bands.normalizedDifference(['SR_B3','SR_B5']).rename('ndwi');
  return ndwi
  .copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames())
  }).median();

Map.addLayer(landsat.clip(geometry), [], 'ndwi_summer', false);
Map.addLayer(landsat.clip(geometry).gt(0), [], 'ndwi_thr', false);

var thr = landsat.gt(0.1);
var mask = thr.updateMask(thr);

Map.addLayer(mask, [], 'ndwi_masked', false);

var pixel_area = mask.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea().divide(1e6));

Map.addLayer(pixel_area.clip(geometry), [], 'ndwi_pixel_area', false);

var lake_area = pixel_area.reduceRegion({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(), geometry: geometry, scale: 100
  }).values().get(0);
  
  
print(ee.Number(lake_area))


The collection you're using (tier 2) combined with the location, has no images for the months of June to October.  You should be using tier 1.

so if there is no images use alternatives collection?

Unless you have a really good reason, you should never use Tier 2.  They're the "bad" images.
